# The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list (but is identical)

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, syntax-error

I am trying to develop a procedure that has this basic structure:

```
select a.*
into #temp1
from OPENQUERY(otherDB,'SELECT ... FROM ...')a
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Data]
       (....)
select *
from #temp1
DROP TABLE #temp1
```

The amount of columns in the results from the `OPENQUERY` is identical to the `INSERT` columns

How could I be catching this error :

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

Comment: You're going to need an minimal working example here.  If your SQL engine is telling you that you have fewer columns in the `SELECT` than the `INSERT`, I'm far more likely to think that it's right and you made a mistake than that the engine is broken.  In other words, *I don't believe it's identical*.

Comment: Does `dbo.Data` have a `IDENTITY` column you are forgetting?

Comment: Don't use "*", spell out the columns.

Comment: Post the code that you tried where the column names are spelled out (instead of `*`)

Comment: The problem lies right in the middle of the segments of your code that you explicitly excluded from your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you try to make more specific the select? Example:

```
insert into dbo.data (col1,col2) select col1,col2.....
```